# Cache misses seem work not properly

Tags: c++, arrays, caching

I wanted to check cache misses with this simple code, trying to allocate e.g. array contains 3 elements and then for array that contains 0.3 million elements, but times for doing something with array elements in both cases are pretty even.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int TAB_SIZE = atoi(argv[1]);
    const int TEST_LEN = atoi(argv[2]);

    srand(time(NULL));

    int *tab = new int [TAB_SIZE];

    for(int i=0; i<TEST_LEN;++i) {
        int index = rand()%TAB_SIZE;
        // do something with random indexed array element
        tab[index] = index;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's my output for 3 element array:

```
marc@E540 ~/projects/simple/cache_test $ time ./a.out 3 100000000

real    0m1.236s
user    0m1.232s
sys     0m0.004s
```

And for 0.3 million element array:

```
marc@E540 ~/projects/simple/cache_test $ time ./a.out 300000 100000000

real    0m1.375s
user    0m1.372s
sys     0m0.000s
```

First array fits in my cache and second doesn't:

```
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

Shouldn't it be way faster when whole array fits in cache or difference isn't that big? Are there more efficient ways to test cache?

Comment: probably huge amounts of code being optimized out, look at the generated assembly code

Comment: I've compiled this with -O0 flag and times don't differ.

Comment: did u look at the generated code

Comment: Yes, but I am not good at assembly. http://pastebin.com/NNbvjgBE

Comment: Try it with read/modify/write, say `tab[index] += index`.

Comment: Times are a bit differ but still not as much as I expected.

Comment: Could you provide the disassembly code?

Comment: It's in comment above

Answer (score 0):

for me on centos with gcc

```
[paul@pmcent work]$ time ./a.out 3 100000000

real    0m1.622s
user    0m1.603s
sys 0m0.000s
[paul@pmcent work]$ time ./a.out 300000 100000000

real    0m2.044s
user    0m2.023s
sys 0m0.000s
[paul@pmcent work]$
```

not an answer but too big for a comment